# Indexing specific Keyword Metadata fields

Tags: taxonomy, si4t

I'm trying to use SI4T to index the value of a Keyword Metadata field into Solr. I've been using SI4T to index DCPs (which I posted a question about not so long ago [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7134/si4t-indexing-component-links-into-solr)). The DCPs are going into Solr fine, but I'm not too sure how to check if a Keyword field contains Metadata only to specifically index a certain field. I kind of know what options I have but what I have tried currently doesn't work.

I don't think (looking at the [SI4T wiki](https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/wiki)) that I can access Metadata from my `SearchIndexCustomFieldMap` field in my Component Template? I did try doing this but it didn't work, no errors just didn't index the Keyword Metadata field.

I have had a look at the `ProcessCustomField` method in the `FieldsProcessor` class which seems to check for a `KeywordField` and if one is found it indexes it's Id, code snippet of this is shown below:

```
 public virtual void ProcessCustomField(ItemField field, FieldProcessorSettings settings = null)
    {
        IndexField targetField = settings.CustomFieldTarget(field.Name);
        IList<string> values = new List<string>();
        if (field is KeywordField)
        {
            values = ((KeywordField)field).Values.Select(k => k.Id.ItemId.ToString()).ToList();
        }
        else if (field is ComponentLinkField)
        {
            values = ((ComponentLinkField)field).Values.Select(c => c.Id.ItemId.ToString()).ToList();
        }
        else if (field is DateField)
        {
            values = ((DateField)field).Values.Select(d => d.ToString("o") + "Z").ToList();
        }
        else if (field is NumberField)
        {
            values = ((NumberField)field).Values.Select(n => n.ToString()).ToList();
        }
        else if (field is TextField)
        {
            values = ((TextField)field).Values;
        }
        AddToData(values, (field is XhtmlField), targetField);
    }
```

Now what I was trying to do with the above is get the Xml of the Keyword Metadata and add it's value to `values`. But I'm not sure if this is the right approach to take?

We are using Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'd add an answer to this so you know what I did to resolve this.

```
if (field is KeywordField)
{
   values = ((KeywordField)field).Values.Select(k => k.Id.ItemId.ToString()).ToList();
}
```

Using the above conditional statement from my initial post, I noticed that `field` is (in this context) a `KeywordField`. From there I have access to the `Metadata` property where I can just use `ItemFields` to pull out the value of a specific `Metadata` field.

Answer (score 3):

The best aproach to achieve this is by extending the TemplateBase of SI4T (see http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/inside-si4t-search-integrations-controlling-what-gets-indexed - last chapter)

something like...

```
Component component = new Component(cp.Component.Id, engine.GetSession());
ItemFields metaFields = new ItemFields(component.Metadata, component.MetadataSchema);

if (metaFields.Contains(categoriefield) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(metaFields[categoriefield].ToString())) 
{
    field = (ItemField)metaFields[categoriefield];
    IList<string> values = new List<string>();
    values = ((KeywordField)field).Values.Select(k => k.Title.ToString()).ToList();

    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        m_processor.SetCustomFieldValue("CUSTOMFIELDNAME", (object)value);
    }
}
```